# Is it lying in wait for/of or laying in wait for/of?

Tags: lie-lay-lain-laid

I’ve seen these two sentences written in two different books:

1. Then the whole army advanced against the three who were laying in wait for it calmly. (*Albanian Folktales and Legends* by Robert Elsie)
2. Many times in the past we had faced attacks from our enemies, but lying in wait of the mightiest army of the world had ever known was a different matter. (*The Siege* by Ismaïl Kadaré translated by David Bellos)

Shouldn’t it be ‘lying in wait for’? And not ‘lying in wait of’ or  ‘laying in wait for’?

Comment: Does [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lie-lay-lain-laid) answer your question?

Comment: Ismaïl Kadaré isn't a native Anglophone, so take no notice of the non-standard preposition usage there. That ***laying / lying*** distinction is just meaningless fodder for pedants.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The distinction is a causative one: laying something makes it lie just like raising something makes it rise and felling a tree makes it fall.

Comment: @tchrist: I'm sure every native Anglophone knows you can only ***lay** bricks*, not ***lie*** them, so you won't find *any* written instance of people explaining [***how to lie bricks***.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=how+to+lie+bricks%2Chow+to+lay+bricks&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) But  an awful lot of people have been perfectly happy to talk about [***laying in wait***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=laying+in+wait&year_start=1819&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) (***and*** get published! :). I can live with that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I should have indicated I was referring to the English translation of renowed scholar David Bellos. Thank you.

Comment: @MónicaQ: Oh. Well that means there's a *translator* involved. And that translator clearly doesn't know English very well - lots of native Anglophones either don't know or don't care about ***laying** in wait*, but they all know you lie in wait ***for*** your victim, not ***of*** him. I don't mind defending native Anglophones who "wrongly" use ***lay***, but if someone is actually getting *paid* to do translation work, I don't think they should get away with that sort of thing! :)

Comment: **lying in wait *for* someone** means to remain hidden while waiting to ambush someone.  **lying in wait *of* someone** could be understood to mean "to be hunkered down, awaiting an assault *by* someone".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are three verbs:

**lie**
lay (past tense)
lain (past participle)  means to be or to stay at rest

**lay**
laid (past tense)
laid (past tense)      means to put or set down

**lie**
lied ( past tense)
lied ( past participle)  as used in "tell a lie"

In your case "laying in wait for" is more appropriate.

Comment: Why do you think people waiting to ambush someone are better described as "to put or set down" than as "to be or to stay at rest"?

Comment: What are they laying, eggs? Are these chickens?

Answer (score 9):

*Garner's Modern English Usage* (2016) says "laying" is a mistake:

[image: Another common mistake is 'laying in wait' for 'lying in wait' quote]

> Another common mistake is *laying in wait* for *lying in wait* -- e.g.:
>
> - "Police say several armed assailants may have been *laying* [read *lying*] in wait at East 39th Street and Park Avenue." Erica Franklin, "14 Unsolved Murders Are Possibly Tied to Drug Sales," *Indianapolis Star*, 11 Oct. 1994, at A1.
> - "Dunlap has been accused of *laying* [read *lying*] in wait until closing time at the Chuck E Cheese restaurant, then systematically shooting the five employees still on duty," Ginny McKibben, "Ex-Friend Links Dunlap to Burger King Robbery." *Denver Post*, 1 Apr. 1995, at B4.
>   [Garner's Modern English Usage - 2016](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Garner_s_Modern_English_Usage/2xv4CwAAQBAJ?gbpv=1&dq=%22laying+in+wait+for%22&pg=PA554&printsec=frontcover)

[image: ngram comparing "lying in wait for" to "laying in wait for"]

[image: ngram comparing "lying in wait of" to "laying in wait of"]

"Lying in wait for" is the correct form,  "lying in wait of" is at best rare nowadays and archaic, if not yet obsolete.

[Lying in wait for](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22lying%20in%20wait%20for%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)

[Laying in wait for](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22laying%20in%20wait%20for%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)

[lying in wait of](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22lying%20in%20wait%20of%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)

[laying in wait of](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22laying%20in%20wait%20of%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)

Comment: The Corpus of Contemporary American English shows 308 instances of *lying in wait* compared to just 29 instances of *laying in wait*.  This makes more sense when you consider that COCA also includes various "non-curated" sources of live speech.

Comment: Just because Google Books has found examples of "lying in wait of" doesn't make it correct; it merely shows it's been used. It's an order of magnitude less than "for", even in its apparent heyday.

Comment: @AndrewLeach It is very  rare and apparently archaic, but that does not mean it should be called incorrect, does it?

Comment: It might be called incorrect if it's so archaic as to be [practically] obsolete. And the recent uptick in *of* may be due to incorrect translation from foreign languages.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I think it is  due instead  to modern criticism relative to religious texts.

Comment: @LPH: eh? What do religious texts have to do with the price of tea in China?

Comment: @Marthaª What do you mean by that? I can't find this text you seem to be referring to in the Google search.

Comment: @LPH https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What%27s_that_got_to_do_with_the...%3F -- "What have religious texts to do with this or anything else?"

Comment: @AndrewLeach I don't think it's irrelevant ; in fact quite a number of these texts do appear in the research and it is well known that religious language is full of archaic forms ; here is for instance the SOED definition of "archaic": "no longer in ordinary use though retained by individuals or for special purposes (e.g.  **poetical, liturgical**)".

Comment: I agree with @AndrewLeach here. It's misleading to suggest that preposition ***of*** is "valid" in [a context like this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=were+lying+in+wait+for%2Cwere+lying+in+wait+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3). It had little currency even two centuries ago, and I'd have thought virtually *every* "current" instance would be citing historical texts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I changed the contested text; don't hesitate to criticize the new version if needed.

Comment: ty for acknowledgment. I didn't *intentionally* withhold an upvote because of that point, but presumably making the comment distracted me. Anyway, I've upvoted now (the relevant amendment is impeccable, imho! :)